# How to use uBlock Origin to block just the page stackexchange.com without blocking the entire stackexchange network?

Tags: firefox, blocking, adblock, ublock-origin, ublock

I've found HNQ are really distracting to me, so I want to block them.  [This question](https://superuser.com/questions/1157967/how-to-block-hot-network-questions-in-the-sidebar-of-stack-exchange-network) has some ways to block them in the sidebar, but the same list exists over at https://stackexchange.com/.  I want to block that page, without blocking all of the rest of stackexchange.  I currently am using

```
|https://stackexchange.com^
```

but that presents a page where I can click-through to access it: I'd rather have it load but present a blank page.  I do this for reddit using

```
reddit.com##body
```

but using a similar filter for stackexchange blocks, for example, all of tex.stackexchange.com.  I suppose I could add an exception filter for every possible subdomain, but there are currently a bit over a hundred and growing, so there has to be a better way.  I tried

```
~stackexchange.com##body
```

which seems like it should work according to [the AdBlock Plus filter cheatsheet](https://adblockplus.org/filter-cheatsheet#elementdomains) which is supposedly supported by uBlock Origin, but that doesn't block anything.

I tried the filters given in [this similar question about youtube](https://superuser.com/questions/1202926/using-ublock-origin-how-do-i-block-a-root-site-without-blocking-sub-pages), but they have the same issues as my current best filter.  How can I filter the body element of stackexchange.com without blocking subdomains?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked question, because that focuses on blocking HNQ in the sidebar, whereas I'm focused on blocking the HNQ page at stackexchange.com.

Comment: It isn't clear what problem you're trying to solve.  Why go to a web page and look at a blank page rather than simply not go to that web page?

Comment: @fixer1234 I find I'm easily distractable and one of the ways I tend to distract myself is by pulling up the webpage and browsing through the list of hot questions.  I want the list to show a blank page as a reminder that This Is Not A Good Use Of My Time.

Comment: Note: I would be happy with any solution that blocks the HNQ list from that page; I can't find a clear selector to use to do that.

Comment: You appear to use a bad syntax: drop the `https://` prefix and use `||` instead of `|`. See [the wiki](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Static-filter-syntax#static-network-filtering).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer attempts to **block Hot Network Questions (HNQ) *only* on Stack Exchange (SE) homepage** (as per [OP's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1374334/how-to-use-ublock-origin-to-block-just-the-page-stackexchange-com-without-blocki/1374766#comment2070939_1374334)).

The HNQ on [SE Homepage](https://stackexchange.com) is inside a div with the ID `question-list` thus the needed filter is `stackexchange.com###question-list`.

This filter will only block HNQ on the SE homepage. It won't block [SE Realtime Questions](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime) (the parent container is `main-area` which is shared with an HNQ list).  Neither will any question lists on any of their other sites block them.  SE uses a div with the ID `question-mini-list` on [their homepage](https://superuser.com/) and the ID `questions` on their [Questions lists](https://superuser.com/questions).